# Cypress custom commands not working when running without --watch

Tags: angular, cypress

Usually I run my tests with:

```
npx ng e2e --watch
```

and it's working fine, but on the CI I am running tests with:

```
npx ng e2e
```

and in this case I am getting webpack errors, all my custom commands are missing.

```
TS2339: Property 'login' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.
```

Any idea what I should look for?

Here is my current config:

```js
{
animationDistanceThreshold:5
baseUrl:"http://localhost:4200/"
blockHosts:null
browsers:Chrome, Firefox, Electron
chromeWebSecurity:false
componentFolder:"cypress/component"
defaultCommandTimeout:4000
env:tsConfig
execTimeout:60000
experimentalComponentTesting:false
experimentalFetchPolyfill:false
experimentalRunEvents:false
experimentalSourceRewriting:false
fileServerFolder:"."
firefoxGcInterval:runMode, openMode
fixturesFolder:"./src/fixtures"
hosts:null
ignoreTestFiles:"*.hot-update.js"
includeShadowDom:false
integrationFolder:"./src/integration"
modifyObstructiveCode:false
nodeVersion:"default"
numTestsKeptInMemory:50
pageLoadTimeout:60000
pluginsFile:"./src/plugins/index"
port:null
projectId:null
reporter:"spec"
reporterOptions:null
requestTimeout:5000
responseTimeout:30000
retries:runMode, openMode
screenshotOnRunFailure:true
screenshotsFolder:"../../dist/cypress/apps/noah-hq-e2e/screenshots"
supportFile:"./src/support/index.ts"
taskTimeout:60000
testFiles:"**/*.*"
trashAssetsBeforeRuns:true
userAgent:null
video:false
videoCompression:32
videosFolder:"../../dist/cypress/apps/noah-hq-e2e/videos"
videoUploadOnPasses:true
viewportHeight:660
viewportWidth:1000
waitForAnimations:true
scrollBehavior:"top"
watchForFileChanges:true
}
```

my commands.ts

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    login(username: string, pass: string): void;
    registerDefaultRoutes(): void;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.visit('/login');

  cy.get('#defaultLoginFormEmail')
    .type(username)
    .should('not.have.class', 'ng-invalid');
  cy.get('#defaultLoginFormPassword')
    .type(password)
    .should('not.have.class', 'ng-invalid');

  cy.get('.btn').click();
});
```

cypress.json

```
{
  "fileServerFolder": ".",
  "fixturesFolder": "./src/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "./src/integration",
  "modifyObstructiveCode": false,
  "pluginsFile": "./src/plugins/index",
  "supportFile": "./src/support/index.ts",
  "video": false,
  "videosFolder": "../../dist/cypress/apps/noah-hq-e2e/videos",
  "screenshotsFolder": "../../dist/cypress/apps/noah-hq-e2e/screenshots",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Comment: And *have* you provided types for your custom commands? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added a command. I beleave the problem might be somewhere in configs. Doe the fact, that the commands are working fine if I use --watch.

Comment: Note that [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Types-for-custom-commands) say the types should be in `support/index.d.ts`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I read this, but its not an issue. It`s also a boilerplate code.